# How do you use the run-parts command?

Tags: linux, cron

For some reason my crontab is not running the hourly/weekly/etc scripts.
It seems to be that run-parts is not working and I cant get it to work on my local machine as well. Is there a mistake in the way I'm using it?

```
fabe@fabetop ~ $ cat /home/fabe/tmp/test.sh 
#!/bin/sh
touch /home/fabe/tmp/test_it
fabe@fabetop ~ $ ls -la /home/fabe/tmp
total 32
drwx------  2 fabe fabe  4096 Feb 20 15:00 .
drwx------ 60 fabe fabe 16384 Feb 20 15:00 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 fabe fabe    39 Feb 20 15:00 test.sh
fabe@fabetop ~ $ run-parts --report /home/fabe/tmp
fabe@fabetop ~ $ ls -la /home/fabe/tmp
total 32
drwx------  2 fabe fabe  4096 Feb 20 15:00 .
drwx------ 60 fabe fabe 16384 Feb 20 15:00 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 fabe fabe    39 Feb 20 15:00 test.sh
```

Comment: What crontab? You have no crontab here. Why are you using `run-parts` anyway? Why not just run the script directly?

Comment: I am not showing the crontab as i have isolated the problem to this command.

As to why run-parts I have many users one for each site and I just use folders in there /home/username/cron/hourly etc which is more convenient then having to edit the crontab all the time (just update the git project and they will run...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is the name of your script. From `man run-parts`:

> If  neither  the  --lsbsysinit  option  nor  the  --regex  option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII  underscores,  and  ASCII  minus- hyphens.

In other words, no extension. Oddly enough, even with the `--lsbsysinit` option, you can't specify a file like `foo.sh` since that matches none of the namespaces covered:

> If  the  --lsbsysinit  option  is  given,  then  the names must not end in .dpkg-old  or .dpkg-dist or .dpkg-new or .dpkg-tmp, and must belong to one or  more  of  the  following  namespaces:  the  LANANA assigned namespace (^[a-z0-9]+$); the LSB hierarchical and reserved    namespaces (^_?([a-z0-9_.]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$); and the Debian cron script namespace (^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$).

So, while `foo.sh` fails, `foo.s-h` or `foo.-sh` will work. I have no idea why they've done it this way but presumably they are following some standard or other.

Anyway, you have 2 options, either rename your scripts to not have an extension  (extensions are optional in *nix anyway) or you can skip using `run-parts` altogether. Use this in your `crontab` instead:

```
find /home/fabe/tmp/ -prune -type f -executable -exec {} \;
```

The command above will find all executable files in the target directory and run them. I think that `-executable` is a GNU extension but you have tagged this as Linux so I assume you have GNU find.

Comment: The is very strange as on RHEL there is a file called `0yum-hourly.cron` which runs with run-parts

Comment: THANK YOU! I was pulling my hair to try to understand why the "busybox" version of run-parts refused to find my "test.sh" script. Renamed it to "test" and now it works. Just insane.

Comment: The suggested `find /home/fabe/tmp/ -prune` returns only that passed directory (`/home/fabe/tmp/`) for me, it doesn't return any scripts within that directory. It works properly with an asterisks at the end --> `find /home/fabe/tmp/* -prune`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this - my cron was silently failing to execute symlinks I had made to files where I kept the .extension.  `run-parts` is really annoying for doing this, god knows why it doesn't run these files.

Comment: @mj3c (sorry, I must have missed this back when you mentioned it) that's because the `-prune` ensures it doesn't descend into subdirectories. If you had a file in the top level, that would have been returned.

Answer (score 6):

Every script placed in folder `/etc/cron.hourly` would run on hourly basis.

However your files needs to be:

- executable,
- match the Debian cron script namespace `(^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$)`.

So for example if you've script with extension (`.sh` in this case), it won't work.

To print the names of the scripts which would be run, try:

```
sudo run-parts --report --test /etc/cron.hourly
```