# How to add new users to a group without specifying?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I googled a bit for this (maybe incorrect keywords), but I didn't find how to do that.

Consider the following commands:

```
useradd -s /bin/bash -m user1
useradd -s /bin/bash -m user2
useradd -s /bin/bash -m user3
```

I want any new user created this way to also be added to a group called `test`, but without needing to specify it each time I run `useradd`. I want this to happen by default.

I mean after creating `user1`, when I run `grep user1 /etc/group`, it should be in two groups: `test` and `user1`.

Is that possible? I am using CentOS.

Comment: well, you do need to change the command in order to add additional groups. per the man pages, use the -G option to list additional groups eg: `useradd -s /bin/bash -m user1 -G test` https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

Comment: "I want to add all of these users to a group called test but I do not want to change the above command." – Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. *Why* cannot you adjust the commands? or use few extra commands?

Comment: @FrankThomas I just want to know for curiosity. It's not a question for a production environment.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks, I just want to know for curiosity. It's not a question for a production environment. Only if that's possible or not.

Comment: Are you looking for `usermod -a -G group user` ?

Comment: @harrymc I know I can change user after creating or set group during creating, but that's just a question if it's possible to have something defined so that all new users are joined a specific group or not. Without any `usermod` or `user add ... -G test`

Comment: Unix does not work this way.  you need to change your command line (with -G) or add additional commands to commit users to group.  your only "default" group is your primary group which matches the user name.

Comment: What Linux are you asking about? Do you also have `adduser` available? Also, if you want to know how to make this happen by default, you need to mention that in your question, so please [edit] and explain exactly what you need.

Comment: @terdon it's CentOS 7.

Comment: Use a function in your `~/.bashrc` with name `useradd` to do `useradd` and `usermod`. See `help command`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can set a default action to be carried out after the new user is created. This is, admittedly rather obliquely, documented in `man useradd` near the end, in the FILES section:

> /etc/shadow-maint/useradd-pre.d/*, /etc/shadow-maint/useradd-post.d/*
>
> Run-part files to execute during user addition. The environment
> variable **ACTION** will be populated with useradd and **SUBJECT** with
> the **username**.  useradd-pre.d will be executed prior to any user
> addition.  useradd-post.d will execute after user addition. If a
> script exits non-zero then execution will terminate.

This means that any scripts placed in the `/etc/shadow-maint/useradd-post.d/` directory will be executed after a new user is created. In those scripts, any use of the environment variable `$SUBJECT` will be replaced with the user name of the newly created used. Now, `run-parts` is a bit strange and requires [very specific naming schemes](https://superuser.com/a/719493/151431). However, in your case, since all you want is that one script, it should be enough to name it something like `01groups`. So, first, create the directories:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/shadow-maint/useradd-post.d/
```

Next, create a text file with the following contents:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
usermod -a -G test "$SUBJECT"
```

Make sure the `test` group exists. If it doesn't, create it first with `sudo groupadd test`.

Finally, save that file as `/etc/shadow-maint/useradd-post.d/01groups` and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/shadow-maint/useradd-post.d/01groups
```

And that's it. If you now create a new user, that user will also be added to your extra group. For example, I tested it on my system using this command:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/bib1 -m -s /bin/bash bib1
```

And then:

```
$ grep bib1 /etc/group
test:x:1003:bib1
bib1:x:1004:
```

As you can see, the new user was automatically added to the extra `test` group. Note that this will now happen for *all* users added to the system by `useradd`. It's probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this but this is one way. I think the easiest way is to extend the `$PATH` variable.
So in bash you do it like this (please replace the path):

```
export PATH="/home/user1/myscripts:$PATH"
```

Put it at the end of `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Then place a script called `useradd` inside the `myscripts` folder. You have to write a short script which does what you want. Call the original `useradd` binary by using an absolute path.

Another way is to replace the original `useradd` binary by a bash script and rename the original. You can run

```
which useradd
```

to see where it is. But your system might get unstable. I recommand using the first way.

Comment: This isn't really answering the question. You are basically saying "it is possible to write something that can do it, but I am not showing you how". A script actually demonstrating how this would work would be an answer, but as it stands, you just have a diversion into the PATH variable and a statement that it would be possible.